# Can I postpone death i.e. increase the lifespan of a person using a mantra?

Tags: mantras, death, life-span

Is there any mantra, which, when recited, increases the lifespan of person? If so, can I recite it for the longevity of my family members'?

Comment: you can use Mahamrynjaya Mantra but you should use it utmost care. You should need a guide or preist to use it. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahamrityunjaya_Mantra ). i think life span of person depends on no of breaths he/she takes, though i do not know what scriptures mention this.